# How to access values from automatically generated Labels?

Tags: java, javafx

Here I receive an `ObservableList` of Products. Then for each Product in the `List` I create a `Label` for the name, price and quantity. I also create two Buttons, to add and remove quantity, altering the value in the label. My problem is in the ´escolherProdutos()´ method, where I want to access the value of each Label respective to de quantity so I can know what quantities of each product are being requested, and I cant seem to access these values from outside the `populateFlowPane()` method. This is probably not the best solution to my problem, and I am a beginner, so if you can help me solve my problem or even have a better way of doing this I would be really grateful.

```
public class EscolherProdutosController 
{
    @FXML private VBox nomesVBox;
    @FXML private VBox precoVBox;
    @FXML private VBox qtdsVBox;
    @FXML private Button escolherBtn;
    
    private static ArrayList<Label> quantidades = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @FXML
    public void initialize() 
    {
        populateFlowPane();
    }   
    
    public void populateFlowPane()
    {
        ObservableList<Produto> produtos = Logic.getProdutos();
        
        produtos.forEach(prod -> {
            HBox hbox = new HBox(5);
            
            Label nome = new Label(prod.getNome());
            Label preco = new Label(String.valueOf(prod.getPreco()));
            Button minus = new Button("-");
            minus.setMinSize(20, 20);
            Label qtd = new Label("0");
            Button plus = new Button("+");
            
            nomesVBox.getChildren().add(nome);
            precoVBox.getChildren().add(preco);
            
            hbox.getChildren().addAll(minus, qtd, plus);
            
            qtdsVBox.getChildren().add(hbox);
            
            //remover unidades do produto
            minus.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
                int quantidade = Integer.parseInt(qtd.getText());
                if(quantidade >= 1)
                {
                    quantidade--;
                    qtd.setText(String.valueOf(quantidade));
                }
            });
            
            //adicionar unidades do produto
            plus.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
                int quantidade = Integer.parseInt(qtd.getText());
                if(quantidade >= 0)
                {
                    quantidade++;
                    qtd.setText(String.valueOf(quantidade));
                }
            });
            
            quantidades.add(qtd);
        });
        
    }
    
    public void escolherProdutos()
    {
        ObservableList<Produto> produtos = Logic.getProdutos();
        produtos.forEach(prod -> {
            quantidades.forEach(qtd -> {
                Logic.escolherProdutos(prod.getIdProduto(),
                Integer.parseInt(qtd.getText()));
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `results`? Also, don't use raw types (`ListView` should be `ListView<SomeType>`, where `SomeType` is the class of the objects whose values are displayed in the list view).

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. It was supposed to be `add(label)`. I added the original code so I could be clearer as to what my problem is and what I want to do. If my question still has problems please tell me so I can correct them.

Comment: Why don't you have the button modify the data in the corresponding `Produto` object (and just make the `List<Produto>` an instance variable, instead of a local variable in the method. Then you don't need to access the labels at all, you just access the data.

Comment: Because `Produto` is a class from a database table and doesnt even have a quantity property. So basically I want to get the Product ID from each product and associate it with the quantity from the label and add them to a `Hashmap`. But since Products can be added and removed from de database I dont know the exact number of products and have to generate the labels and buttons automatically

Comment: Then I'd create another class that wraps a `Produto` and a quantity. You should never store data in UI elements.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Im going to try what you are saying and see if it solves it. Thanks for all the help and sorry for not being clear enough from the start. On a separate subject, can you point me in the direction of some guidelines or something to make my questions on StackOverflow better and clearer? Im really not used to posting questions

Comment: The best way to write a good question is to narrow everything down to a single, focused question, and then to write a standalone app that others can copy, paste, and run, that demonstrates the question. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62451115/) (while admittedly a bit simpler than yours) is a good example. In your case, you could write a very simple version of your `Produto` class, then write a standalone app that hard-codes a few instances and then use the code you have to display them. Then in the button handler explain that you want to get the quantities.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably add them to a list and access them accordingly im not sure what you need from them because you are being vague but take a look at the code sample below

```
public class MySceneController {

    @FXML private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<Label> labelList = new ArrayList<>();

    @FXML
    public void initialize()
    {
        populateListView();
    }

    public void populateListView()
    {
        ObservableList<Products> products = Logic.getProducts();

        products.forEach(prod -> {
            Label label = new Label(prod.getName());

            //Add them to a list here
            labelList.add(label);

            listView.getItems().addAll(results);
        });
    }


    public void doSomething()
    {
        for (Label label : labelList) {//Maybe iterate through the list depending on what you need
            //do something
        }
        //Here is where I need to access the label values
    }

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to store the list of `Product`s?

Comment: @James_D He should be able to pull the list from the `Logic.getProducts();` function but because he is vague im not really sure what he's trying to do i figured maybe he wanted to modify the label

Comment: Sorry for being too vague. My attempt to keep things simple backfired. As soon as I can I will update this question to be more specific, including the original code. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Maybe it's not the best solution, but it works for me. What I did was create a `HashMap` where the product ID is the key and the quantity is the value.

Then for the add and remove buttons, I simply replace the value for the corresponding key in the `HashMap`. Doing this, I can then use it as input for the `escolherProdutos()` method from the `Logic` class, to select the products.

```
public class EscolherProdutosController 
{
    @FXML private VBox nomesVBox;
    @FXML private VBox precoVBox;
    @FXML private VBox qtdsVBox;
    
    private HashMap<BigDecimal, Integer> quantidades = new HashMap<>();

    
    
    @FXML
    public void initialize() 
    {
        populateFlowPane();
    }   
    
    public void populateFlowPane()
    {
        ObservableList<Produto> produtos = Logic.getProdutos();
        
        
        produtos.forEach(prod -> {
            HBox hbox = new HBox(5);
            
            Label nome = new Label(prod.getNome());
            Label preco = new Label(String.valueOf(prod.getPreco()));
            Button minus = new Button("-");
            minus.setMinSize(20, 20);
            Label qtd = new Label("0");
            Button plus = new Button("+");
            
            nomesVBox.getChildren().add(nome);
            precoVBox.getChildren().add(preco);
            
            hbox.getChildren().addAll(minus, qtd, plus);
            
            qtdsVBox.getChildren().add(hbox);
            
            //remover unidades do produto
            minus.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
                Integer quantidade = Integer.parseInt(qtd.getText());
                if(quantidade >= 1)
                {
                    quantidade--;
                    qtd.setText(String.valueOf(quantidade));
                    
                    if(quantidades.containsKey(prod.getIdProduto()))
                        quantidades.replace(prod.getIdProduto(), quantidade);
                    else
                        quantidades.put(prod.getIdProduto(), quantidade);
                }
            });
            
            //adicionar unidades do produto
            plus.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
                Integer quantidade = Integer.parseInt(qtd.getText());
                if(quantidade >= 0)
                {
                    quantidade++;
                    qtd.setText(String.valueOf(quantidade));
                    
                    if(quantidades.containsKey(prod.getIdProduto()))
                        quantidades.replace(prod.getIdProduto(), quantidade);
                    else
                        quantidades.put(prod.getIdProduto(), quantidade);
                }
            });
        });
        
    }
    
    public void escolherProdutos()
    {
        Logic.escolherProdutos(quantidades);
    }
```