# How to make the javafx animation using path transition smooth?

Tags: java, animation, javafx

My goal for now is to make the animation of a little circle, going along the path of a big circle. In the future, I would need to dynamically change the speed of revolution using a slider, but that is not a problem now. I can't figure out how to make this animation smooth? By this I mean that I want my little circle to not slow down when it reaches the end of animation. Is this possible using path transition? Or should I use some other method to implement animation in order for it to be smooth?

Here is what I have for now:

```
import javafx.animation.*;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
    import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
    import javafx.scene.shape.*;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.util.Duration;

    public class SpinningCircles extends Application {

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        int BigCircRad = 200;
        int BigCircX = 750;
        int BigCircY = 400;
        double duration = 1;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch();
        }
        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage){
            Circle cir1 = new Circle(BigCircRad);
            Circle cir2 = new Circle(BigCircRad/10);

            cir1.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            cir2.setFill(Color.WHITE);

            cir1.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
            cir2.setStroke(Color.BLUE);

            cir1.setStrokeWidth(4);
            cir2.setStrokeWidth(4);

            cir1.setCenterX(BigCircX);
            cir2.setCenterX(BigCircX);

            cir1.setCenterY(BigCircY);
            cir2.setCenterY(BigCircY-BigCircRad);

            PathTransition pt = new PathTransition();
            pt.setNode(cir2);
            pt.setDuration(Duration.seconds(duration));
            pt.setPath(cir1);
            pt.setDelay(Duration.seconds(1));
            pt.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
            pt.play();

            root.getChildren().addAll(cir1, cir2);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 500);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setTitle("Spinning circles");
            stage.setMaximized(true);
            stage.setFullScreen(true);
            stage.show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [set the interpolator](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Transition.html#interpolatorProperty) for the animation.

From the docs, the interpolator

> Controls the timing for acceleration and deceleration at each
>   Transition cycle.
>
> Default interpolator is set to Interpolator.EASE_BOTH.

The default, [`Interpolator.EASE_BOTH`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Interpolator.html#EASE_BOTH)

> will make an animation start slow, then accelerate and slow down again towards the end, all in a smooth manner.

Instead, use a [`LINEAR`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Interpolator.html#LINEAR) interpolator:

```
    pt.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
```

Note the interpolator must be set before the animation is started:

```
    PathTransition pt = new PathTransition();
    pt.setNode(cir2);
    pt.setDuration(Duration.seconds(duration));
    pt.setPath(cir1);
    pt.setDelay(Duration.seconds(1));
    pt.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

    pt.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);

    pt.play();
```

Comment: Wow, that was so helpfull!!! Thanks a lot for this info!